# LVM mirror disk failed, can't be removed, so LV can't be accessed

Tags: fedora, lvm, raid

I'm trying to help someone resurrect a RAID1 mirrored LVM logical volume on an old server running Fedora 20 (lvm2-2.0.2.106, linux 3.19.8-100). One of the disks in the mirror is dead. The LV is systemvg/home.

We tried to convert from RAID1 to linear:

```
lvconvert -m0 systemvg/home
  PV qtva6m-iBhc-q3Zt-At1U-FiWH-iZd8-tjpR0u not recognised. Is the device missing?
  Cannot change VG systemvg while PVs are missing.
  Consider vgreduce --removemissing.
```

So we tried:

```
vgreduce --removemissing systemvg
  PV qtva6m-iBhc-q3Zt-At1U-FiWH-iZd8-tjpR0u not recognised. Is the device missing?
  PV qtva6m-iBhc-q3Zt-At1U-FiWH-iZd8-tjpR0u not recognised. Is the device missing?
  WARNING: Partial LV home needs to be repaired or removed. 
  WARNING: Partial LV home_rmeta_1 needs to be repaired or removed. 
  WARNING: Partial LV home_rimage_1 needs to be repaired or removed. 
  There are still partial LVs in VG systemvg.
  To remove them unconditionally use: vgreduce --removemissing --force.
  Proceeding to remove empty missing PVs.
```

which seems to imply that the LV needs to be repaired first. So we tried:

```
lvconvert --repair systemvg/home
  PV qtva6m-iBhc-q3Zt-At1U-FiWH-iZd8-tjpR0u not recognised. Is the device missing?
Attempt to replace failed RAID images (requires full device resync)? [y/n]: y
  device-mapper: create ioctl on systemvg-home_rmeta_2 failed: Device or resource busy
  Failed to suspend systemvg/home before committing changes
  Failed to replace faulty devices in systemvg/home.
  Device '/dev/sdc' has been left open (1 remaining references).
  Device '/dev/sda1' has been left open (1 remaining references).
  Internal error: 2 device(s) were left open and have been closed.
```

We would try `vgreduce --removemissing --force` but the message associated with that might seem to imply that the LV would be "removed unconditionaly", and that doesn't sound like something we want.

How can we just break the mirror and recover data from the healthy disk?